# How can someone structure a PostgreSQL query that returns high integer numbers like 534,000,000 to 534m or 1,320,000,000 to 1.3 b

Tags: python, postgresql

I came across this post: https://www.sisense.com/blog/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-in-postgres-mysql-and-redshift/ and they mentioned how to format currency data using `money` datatype.

I actually really like the human readable approach of transforming large numbers with several digits. I'm trying to figure out how to create an SQL query to achieve such. Sadly the blog only teases this in a picture, without the code...

So I'm pretty stuck here, I would like to implement this in my stock market dashboard, how could I approach this?

more examples:

1230 = 1.2k

12,312,312 = 12.3 m

Comment: You're asking about formatting, not querying. That's a job for the client, not SQL. SQL, the language, is pretty bad at text manipulations and formatting.

Comment: `how to format currency data using money datatype` that's **definitely not** what the `money` type is about. It's a *type*, not a formatting function. Which makes that a pretty bad article, especially once you consider you have no control over how the monetary amount actually looks. What symbol? Before or after the amount? Do negative amounts use a sign or parentheses? Or a different color? All of this depends on the actual *report* or *dashboard* you want to create. The same user will need different formats for different reports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the dashboard should take care of data formatting for display.

If you insist on using the DB for that, then the PostgreSQL  `pg_size_pretty` function can convert numbers into "human readable" representations.

Comment: I only feel like it is necessary because I am serving a lot of data (multiple tables of stock market information). I'm afraid if I use a lot of python functions for transformations then my dashboard will slow down. I would rather go with performance. I'm a junior developer so If you think It's a bad idea then I would kindly like to know.

Comment: I just tried your `pg_size_pretty` method, It's appending memory sizes as opposed to numerical digits in string format. (Gb instead of M, gigabytes instead of millions) But yes this is exactly the type of transformation I'm searching for, do you know if I can edit pg_size_pretty?